# How can I automatically select a new background when my external monitor disconnects?

Tags: software-recommendation, multiple-monitors, desktop-background

I have this image:

[image: Desktop background]

Currently, this is stretched across two monitors (connected via VGA) and it works perfectly. What I want to be able to do is, when I disconnect my monitor, be able to switch to a cropped version of that image automatically (because I've played around with settings which have gotten me no where). This is the image I want to switch to, so you get an idea...

[image: Dropbox_4k_cropped]

Is there software or script... some kind of solution for Ubuntu 14.04 that will assist in this?

EDIT:

This is what it would look like if I DON'T change the settings:

[image: Not Changed]

If I do change it, I can't get anything better than:

[image: FIll_1]

(Text all squashed together)

-or-

[image: FILL_2]

(Zoomed to center)

Comment: Doesn't it automatically shrink the image so that it fits to the single screen configuration?

Comment: No, in fact I'll edit my question to show what it would look like...